# How to call adapter inside json which is inside ACTIVITY

Tags: android

I want to call adapter inside json which is inside ACTIVITY I having difficulty in calling that can anyone help me doing it please help, name of my adapater is bookinghistoryadapter 
I am new to android working with activity listview 
I have attached my whole class please look into it

```
public class BookingHistoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private BookingHistoryparsedata bookingHistoryparsedata;

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog = null;
    private String TAG;
    private ListView ll_booking_results;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_booking_history);
        String url = "";
        hitInitialUrl(url);

    }

       private void hitInitialUrl(String url){

                progressDialog.show();
                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
                StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "onResponse : " + response);

        //                JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                        try {
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            String statusCode = jsonObject.getString("statusCode");
                            if (statusCode.equalsIgnoreCase("ok")){
                                Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: " + jsonObject.toString());

                                JSONArray dataobject = new JSONArray(jsonObject.getString("data"));


                                if (dataobject.length() > 0) {
                                    for (int i = 0; i < dataobject.length(); i++) {
                                        JSONObject dataObejct = dataobject.getJSONObject(i);
                                        try {
                                            BookingHistoryData bookingHistoryData = parseBookingConfirmation(dataObejct);
                                            BookingHistoryAdapter adapter = new BookingHistoryAdapter(BookingHistoryFragment.this,BookingHistoryData.tripChart )
                                            Log.e(TAG, "onResponse:   " + BookingHistoryData.tripChart.size());
                                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                                            Log.e(TAG, "onResponse: " + e.toString());
                                        }

                                    }
                                }   
                            }

                        }catch (JSONException e){
                            Log.e(TAG, "exception: " + e.getMessage() );
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();

                    }
                });
                queue.add(request);
            }
```

Comment: What you want to exactly with your adapter? You have already created your adapter's object :- BookingHistoryAdapter adapter = new BookingHistoryAdapter(BookingHistoryFragment.this,BookingHistoryData.tripChart )

Comment: error: constructor BookingHistoryAdapter in class BookingHistoryAdapter cannot be applied to given types;
required: no arguments
found: BookingHistoryActivity,List<TripChart>
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

This is the error I am getting

Comment: Ok. Please show me the adapter constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this code and check if it works and if it worked I will edit answer with explanation.

```
        BookingHistoryData bookingHistoryData = parseBookingConfirmation(dataObejct);
    BookingHistoryAdapter adapter = new BookingHistoryAdapter(BookingHistoryFragment.this, bookingHistoryData.tripChart);
    Log.e(TAG, "onResponse:   " + bookingHistoryData.tripChart.size());
```

Comment: BookingHistoryAdapter adapter = new BookingHistoryAdapter(BookingHistoryFragment.this, bookingHistoryData.tripChart);
 this line is showing error

Comment: put cursor on red line and press alt+enter and choose create constructor

Comment: Actually your constructor is not accepting parameters which you are sending create new constructor and delete previous one.